# Drupal 7 translate date format using locales

Tags: php, drupal

My drupal site has many languages. I need to translate dates.

In admin panel I have this page:
configuration->Regional languages->Date and Time->Formats.

There I can add different formats and then choose them everywhere.
Something like: 'Y-m-d, Y'. In english in will be 2014-10-10, Monday. And I need a translations for all languages.

I added locales of needful languages on server. In PHP it works good:

```
if($lang == 'zh'){
   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'zh_CN.utf8');
   $date = strftime('%Y %B %d %A, %H:%M  ', $date->getTimestamp()); // returns chineeze, it's ok
}
```

But I need to implement these locales not to one template, but somewhere in drupal core. To work with them from admin panel. I can't find no information about this.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the locale date settings in admin/config/regional/date-time/locale   ?

You can set your format for each date type for each installed language.
I suppose you have already installed the [Internationalization](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) module.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal sets locale on bootstrap step, you can put for example

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL');
```

in your settings.php, it will override the bootstrap setting